# select from table A only if all status is the same in table B

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with individuals and a second table with album records and a status.

I am in need of assistance with writing a view that selects ONLY if both records in that Album table have a status of true. (Select only the individuals from the indivTable where all albumStatus=1)

What I need is a bit more because, if one individual has two albums, one with a status of true and the other with the status of false.
I want to disqualify that individual from being selected and im not able to figure out how to accomplish this.

Grateful for any assistance that could be provided.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from individuals i where (select count(1) from albums a where status != 1 and individualID = i.individualID) = 0
```

Comment: Tip: When checking for the existence of one or more rows it is more efficient to use [`EXISTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) rather than getting an exact [`COUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) and then comparing the value to zero.

Answer (score 1):

The query below also checks if the individual has at least one album (they don't count either right?)

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.* 
FROM Individuals AS i
INNER JOIN Albums AS a
    ON i.ArtistID = a.ArtistID 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM Albums AS a2
    WHERE a2.ArtistID = i.ArtistID 
    AND a2.Status = 0
)
```